# Sort, groupby, and get a row and row+1 for a specific column value?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, multi-index

```
        C1  route_Seq   Connection_time     Mod_trans
        R1  1   10                          road
        R1  2   2                            air
        R1  3   4                            air
        R1  4   2                           road
        R1  5   3                            air
        R1  6   4                           road
        R2  1   3                           road
        R2  2   2                            air
        R3  1   1                           road
        R3  2   2                            air
```

I would like to group by my data based on value of column "C1" and sort based on their "route_Seq". So with each C1 the route_Seq are sorted.

Then I would like to sum the value of column "Connection_time" in each group for the rows where the Mod_trans is "road" and one row after. IF road is the last turn in the group then the sum only road's Connection_time.

Desired answer:

```
    C1  Connection_time   Mod_trans
    R1     12  road
    R1     5  road
    R1     4  road
    R2     3  road
    R3     5  road
```

I have tried this code but It instead of giving me the sum of  the two consecutive ones, it sums all the rows after each "road".

```
df.set_index(['C1','Mod_trans',(df['Mod_trans'] == 'road').cumsum()]).sum(level=[0,2]).reset_index().assign(Mod_trans='road')
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['CumRoad'] = (df.sort_values('route_Seq')
                   .groupby('C1')
                   .apply(lambda x: (x['Mod_trans']=='road').cumsum()).values)

df_out = (df.groupby(['C1','CumRoad'])
            .apply(lambda x: x.head(2)['Connection_time'].sum())
            .reset_index())

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   C1  CumRoad   0
0  R1        1  12
1  R1        2   5
2  R1        3   4
3  R2        1   5
4  R3        1   3
```

Answer (score 3):

Still using the same idea like before , `ffill` with `limit` to limit the new row , and `cumsum` to create the subid for `groupby`

```
df['cumid']=df.Mod_trans.eq('road').groupby(df['C1']).cumsum()
s=df['Mod_trans'].where(df['Mod_trans'].eq('road'))
df['newroad']=s.groupby([df.C1,df.cumid]).ffill(limit=1)
df['cumid']=df.Mod_trans.eq('road').groupby(df['C1']).cumsum()
df=df.loc[df.newroad=='road',:]
df.groupby(['C1','cumid','newroad'])['Connection_time'].sum()
Out[285]: 
C1  cumid  newroad
R1  1.0    road       12
    2.0    road        5
    3.0    road        4
R2  1.0    road        5
R3  1.0    road        3
Name: Connection_time, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Also the answer, Thanks again.